# Best Practices: sharing files between projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, projects-and-solutions, workspace

I'm using Eclipse (Helios 3.6.2) and Android SDK.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using symlinks?

```
Template Project: this is the "Main" Project. All other projects will derive from this. 
- src
  - A.java
  - B.java
- layout
  - j.xml
  - l.xml
- drawable
  - x.png
  - y.png


Customer 1 Project:
- src
  - A.java (from template)
  - B.java (not from template. custom file used only in this project)
- layout
  - j.xml  (from template)
  - l.xml  (not from template. custom file used only in this project)
- drawable
  - x.png  (from template)
  - y.png  (not from template. custom file used only in this project)


Customer 2 Project:
- src
  - A.java (from template)
  - B.java (from template)
- layout
  - j.xml  (from template)
  - l.xml  (from template)
- drawable
  - x.png  (not from template. custom file used only in this project)
  - y.png  (not from template. custom file used only in this project)


Customer "N" Project:
  and so on with many combinations of using/not using from template...
  (This is for illustration only. My real projects have hundreds of files of course)
```

I'm kinda rookie in Eclipse. In VisualStudio I can do this by adding files by reference. I couldn't find something similar to this in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a project reference, but I don´t think this is exactly what you are looking for. So here is a brief explanation:
You got to have `Customer 1 Project` and `Template Project` in your current workspace. Then right-click on `Customer 1 Project` in the `Package Explorer` and select `Build Path -> Configure Build Path...` Here go to `Projects` tab and select `Add...`. Here select your `Template project`.

This solution might lead to a problem if `B.java` from `Customer 1 Project` and `Template Project` is in the same package (which it probably is). So you have to choose another name for that class.

Comment: That way doesn't fit my needs. Thanks anyway.